# NativeScript 6 with HMR app is restarted on every change

Tags: nativescript

I am testing on a physical Android device (Note 9) using NativeScript 6.2.0.  When I make a change, HMR activates and displays the following:

```html
JS: HMR: Checking for updates to the bundle with hmr hash 2e86b3ce6c9f6a005362.
JS: HMR: The following modules were updated:
JS: HMR:          ↻ ./components/friends/add_friends/add_friends.xml
JS: HMR: Successfully applied update with hmr hash 2e86b3ce6c9f6a005362. App is up to date.
Restarting application on device 278165d4781c7ece...
JS: HMR: Hot Module Replacement Enabled. Waiting for signal.
JS: HMR: Checking for updates to the bundle with hmr hash 2e86b3ce6c9f6a005362.
JS: HMR: The following modules were updated:
JS: HMR:          ↻ ./components/friends/add_friends/add_friends.xml
JS: HMR: Successfully applied update with hmr hash 2e86b3ce6c9f6a005362. App is up to date.
JS: topmost() is deprecated. Use Frame.topmost() instead.
device: 278165d4781c7ece debug port: 40000
```

Notice that the app is restarted even though I just changed the text in one of the labels.

Here is my package.json

```html
{
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "io.company.app",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "6.2.0"
    }
  },
  "main": "app.js",
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "dependencies": {
    "@nstudio/nativescript-camera-plus": "^3.0.3",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-loading-indicator": "^1.0.0",
    "nativescript": "^6.2.0",
    "nativescript-contacts": "^1.6.2",
    "nativescript-fonticon": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-masked-text-field": "4.0.3",
    "nativescript-permissions": "^1.3.8",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "2.0.5",
    "tns-core-modules": "6.2.0",
    "tns-platform-declarations": "6.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "1.3.0",
    "typescript": "3.4.5"
  },
  "gitHead": "f28dbc60d74dd2cef4b645afd8fdd63bbb12c73e",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application"
}
```

Am I missing some setting that would allow HMR to work properly?

EDIT:  Furthermore, it does not seem that HMR loads css changes.  I have to make a space change in one of the ts files for the css to be loaded.  This whole thing makes HMR useless.

Thanks

Comment: Please, specify the exact command and actions you are executing. From your logs it seems you are using `tns debug android` command. Do you pass any additional flags?

The HMR itself should work without further configuration. Can you send your full log and the exact command you execute.

Comment: Do you have multiple pages in your app? Are you applying this change in your home or root page?

Comment: @Vladimirov, I am using tns debug android, but I tried using the --hrm flag as well as tried to launch the app from Sidekick.  Same result

Comment: @Manoj I do have multiple pages.  I am applying it to one of the additional pages, not the root.  But the same happens regardless which page I made the change to.

Comment: I'm not sure, HMR seems to work as expected on my end. Are you using `topmost()` anywhere in your code?

Comment: I saw that.  I changed it everywhere to Frame.topmost(), but I still get this message.  I wonder if it is a plugin that uses it.

Comment: The funny thing is that HMR works properly on my other computer, but not on this one but I cannot spot the difference.

Comment: It seems you have nativescript@6.2.0 as dependency to your project. Do you really need it? Or most probably when you attempted to upgrade nativescript to the latest version you've omitted the -g switch and that's how it has appeared as dependency to your project.

Comment: You are right.  I do not need it. I just removed it but this did not made and difference.  The app still reloads on every change.

Comment: The application is refreshed only when *.hot-update files are transferred on device. In this case, the output from CLI looks like:
`Successfully transferred bundle.944f56014a2831e3bd50.hot-update.js on device emulator-5554.
Successfully transferred 944f56014a2831e3bd50.hot-update.json on device emulator-5554.
Refreshing application on device emulator-5554...`

In case when there are additional files(except *.hot-updates) that are transferred on device, the application is always restarted. So, can you check in your console output what files are transferred on device?

Comment: @Fatme, check the question.  In the beginning, I posted the exact output from the console when I make a change to one of the XML files.  If I understand HMR correctly, in this situation the app should not be restarted.

Comment: Yep, HMR should work in your case without additional setup. However, I tried to reproduce the issue with hello world application using your dependencies, but without success. The log you've provided at the beginning of the question is not enough to further investigate the problem. We'll need the full log of the command - the whole output from `tns debug android --log trace` or a sample project demonstrating the behavior of HMR.

Comment: Are you using scss or plain css, becuase I am starting in nativescript, and so I added scss (with the needed support npm install) and it does not hmr correctly, now I tried a new project with just css (same hello world angular) and it does work, so maybe thats the issue? update - I see you do not have the scss dependencies so never mind

Comment: Yeah, I am using plain css

Comment: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/9507

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue:

I did a rm -rf node_modules and then npm update and npm install, and now i have HMR (on the scss project too) - ios on a mac

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem after changed the applicationId in the app.gradle. I set back the first applicationId. It is working now.